# Jest and React Testing Library - break down in separate tests instead of a large sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Let's say I want to test a component that renders 3 spans

```
const MyComp: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>span 1</span>
      <span>span 2</span>
      <span>span 3</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My test would look something like:

```
test('MyComp', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<MyComp />);

  // Span 1
  expect(getByText('span 1')).toBeVisible();

  // Span 2
  expect(getByText('span 2')).toBeVisible();

  // Span 3
  expect(getByText('span 3')).toBeVisible();
});
```

and the result

```
PASS  src/app/OrderDetails/OrderDetails/MyComp.test.tsx
```

Now I have pretty big components in my project and I would like to breakdown the tests so that:

- I can see all the failing steps at once
- I can make it clear what each step is testing without using comments
- I can avoid rerendering the whole component for each tests

**OPTION 1:**

How can I do something like this ? (I guess I need to prevent jest from cleaning up the virtual DOM in between tests)

```
describe('MyComp', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<MyComp />);

  test('Span 1 is rendered correctly', () => {
    expect(getByText('span 1')).toBeVisible();
  });

  test('Span 2 is rendered correctly', () => {
    expect(getByText('span 2')).toBeVisible();
  });

  test('Span 3 is rendered correctly', () => {
    expect(getByText('span 3')).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

THIS FAILS as in the second test the DOM has been cleaned up.

**OPTION 2:**

Of course I can make it work by rendering the component in each tests but that would probably hurt the performance. Also, whatever DOM manipulation is done in test 1 is lost in test 2 if let's say I wanted to carry on from there.

```
describe('MyComp', () => {
  test('Span 1 is rendered correctly', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<MyComp />);
    expect(getByText('span 1')).toBeVisible();
  });

  test('Span 2 is rendered correctly', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<MyComp />);
    expect(getByText('span 2')).toBeVisible();
  });

  test('Span 3 is rendered correctly', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<MyComp />);
    expect(getByText('span 3')).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

**CONCLUSION:**

My main concern here is readability of the test code and test results (one long test with comments < several small tests with good test names).

Comment: You can always turn off automatic DOM cleaning in Jest

Comment: @AminPaks Is there a way to do this for one test suite only ? Otherwise I would have to do a manual clean up everywhere

Comment: AFAIK there’s not for only one test suite.

Comment: I personally would go with option 2. If you worry about losing DOM manipulations create a `setup` function that renders, manipulate and returns the result of `render`